# Devise Form for create belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, nested-forms

I need user to be able to create a company in user signup:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable

  belongs_to :company
end
```

And form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { role: 'form' }) do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :company_name %>
    **** how to add company name? ****
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>
  <%= f.submit t('.sign_up', default: 'Sign up'), class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

I know how to process the form later, I just don't know how to create the form.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use from the set of existing parent companies:-

```
<%= f.collection_select(:company_id, Company.all, :id, :name) %>
```

If you want to create a new company from within users controller, simply read it from params and create one.

```
@user = User.new(params[:resource_name])
new_company = Company.create(name: params[:resource_name][:company_name])
@user.company_id = new_company.id
@user.save
```